# Why does this incorrect std::function initialization compile using MSVC?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, visual-c++

Came across an interesting issue today started by my own typo. I created a lambda that takes in a reference to a struct and incorrectly set it to a std::function that receives it's argument by value.

Here's a more concise version:

```
#include <functional>

struct InputStruct
{
    int i;
    InputStruct(): i(1){}
};

void function_rcv(std::function<bool(InputStruct)> & func_ref)
{
    InputStruct in;
    func_ref(in);
}


int main()
{
    std::function<bool(InputStruct)> my_func = [](InputStruct & in)->bool{return in.i==1;};
    function_rcv(my_func);
}
```

Checking with [godbolt](https://godbolt.org) shows this compiles successfully with MSVC, but fails for both Clang and GCC.

Interestingly enough, using a primitive instead of a struct fails compilation on all three compilers.

Is this a bug in the MSVC compiler?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @NathanOliver Fun stuff. I'll have to submit a bug to Microsoft when I get a chance.

Comment: @NathanOliver looking at  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function I can't see anything which explicitly forbids that constructor...

Comment: It's just the usual "MSVC allows temporary to bind to lvalue reference". Compile with `/Zc:referenceBinding` and it won't compile.

Comment: @SergeyA I believe the note on constructor 5 has the reason (*This constructor does not participate in overload resolution unless f is Callable for argument types `Args...` and return type `R`.*).  `std::function<bool(InputStruct)>` can take a rvalue, but `[](InputStruct & in)->bool` can't, so it should fail.

Comment: @geza I didn't think that flag applied to function types as well, but you are correct that adding that flag causes compilation to fail.

Comment: @mascoj: I'm not sure I understand you. This option applies to all non-const lvalue references, it doesn't matter in what context it is written.

Comment: @NathanOliver, sure, but the way I read it, `Args...` in this conext would refer to non-const qualified `InputStruct` objects, which are not rvalues - and `InputStruct& `should be able to bind to those?

Comment: @SergeyA If they are lvalues, sure.  The problem is `std::function`'s `operator()` is going to call `INVOKE<R>(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...)` for the underlying function object and if an rvalue is passed to `operator()` then the underlying function object will get an rvalue, which can't bind to an lvalue reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver sure, but the error seems to be reported at the constructor, not when the callable is called - and I am just not sure what specific wording prohibit calling the constructor.

Comment: @SergeyA: the constructor has to create a function (instantiate a wrapper) which does the call. So the compilation cannot succeed. And I think that the constructor actually disabled with SFINAE (to get a good quality error message, instead of getting a huge hard-to-read error message pointing deep inside the implementation of `std::function`).

Comment: @mascoj Instead of setting that single compiler option you might consider using the [`/permissive-`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=vs-2017) option. It enables [additional options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-conformance?view=vs-2017) for more standards-conforming behavior.

Comment: @geza Sorry my terminology isn't the best way to describe what I am saying. I guess what I am stuck on is `std::function<bool(InputStruct)> func1` and `std::function<bool(InputStruct&)> func2` are different types no? Without the `/Zc:referenceBinding` flag, how is `func1 = func2` a valid operation?

Comment: `std::function` can wrap any compatible callable object. `func2` is a callable object. It wouldn't normally be compatible (`func1` takes its argument by value and passes it along to a callable that wants it by non-const reference), but MSVC allows such forwarding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In summary: it is not a compiler bug. MSVC accepts this code because of its default non-conforming behavior, but it can be made standard-conforming with a switch.

First of all, I need to clarify `std::function`'s one aspect: it accepts a function (in general, *Callable*) which signature is not a perfect match, but the parameters can be converted. Consider:

```
using intFn = void (int);
void fn(short);

intFn *a = fn;               // doesn't compile
std::function<intFn> b = fn; // compiles!
```

Here, `intFn` a function type which has an `int` parameter, while the function `fn` has a `short` parameter. The simple function pointer `a`, cannot be set to point to `fn`, as the type of the parameter differ (`int` vs `short`). But, `std::function` allows this, so `b` can be set to point to `fn`.

In your example, `std::function` has an `InputStruct` parameter by value, while the lambda has a non-const lvalue reference `InputStruct &`. When `std::function` `std::forward`s its parameter, it becomes an xvalue, which cannot be bound to the lambda's lvalue reference parameter. That's why standard conforming compilers don't accept this code.

Why does MSVC accept this code? Because it has non-conforming behavior by default: it allows binding class temporaries (and xvalues) to non-const lvalue references. You can disable this behavior with `/Zc:referenceBinding` (or the older `/Za` option). If you use this switch, MSVC rejects your example.

Comment: Well put. Thank you for the full breakdown.